# Bubble Sort returning different results with same input (not out of bounds error based on trace)

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am having an interesting problem that I can't seem to suss out while working on a bubble sort problem. Take in up to 25 integers and sort them from lowest to highest value and reprint the array. This is the code I have written up that logically works on paper:

```
#include <iostream>

void bubbleSort (int unsorted[25], int sorted[25], int numItems);
void getInput   (int unsorted[25], int toSort[25], int& numItems);
void printArray (int toPrint[25], int& numItems);

int main () {
  int numItems = 25;
  int unsorted[25];
  int sorted[25];

  getInput(unsorted, sorted, numItems);
  printArray(unsorted, numItems);

  bubbleSort(unsorted, sorted, numItems);

  printArray(sorted, numItems);

  return 0;
}

void bubbleSort (int unsorted[25], int sorted[25], int numItems) {
  int temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < numItems - i; j++)
      if (sorted[j] > sorted[j+1]) {
        temp = sorted[j];
        sorted[j] = sorted[j+1];
        sorted[j+1] = temp;
      }
}

void getInput (int unsorted[25], int toSort[25], int& numItems) {
  int val;
  cout << "Please enter up to 25 integers, one at a time\n"
       << "If less than 25 are to be added, enter '-999' to stop\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    cin >> val;
    if (val == -999) {
      numItems = i;
      break;
    }
    unsorted[i] = val;
    toSort[i]   = val;
  }
  cout << "\nUser input complete\n";
} 

void printArray (int toPrint[25], int& numItems) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    cout << " [" << toPrint[i] << "] ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that given the same input, in my case I am using [3, 2, 4, 1, 5] as it was what initially tipped me off to the bug, I can get different output. specifically one of these two with seemingly no rhyme or reason that I can see :

```
User input complete
[3]  [2]  [4]  [1]  [5] -> entered numbers

[0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4] -> sorted numbers
```

or :

```
User input complete
[3]  [2]  [4]  [1]  [5] -> entered numbers

[1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5] -> sorted numbers
```

Both outputs are from the same compiled program and seems to just randomly decide if it'll chop off my highest value and replace it with a 0. I know it isn't actually random but I can't figure what is causing it for the life of me.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to single-step through your sorting routine, watching for that pesky 0?

Comment: Why are you passing `unsorted` to the `bubbleSort` function, and do not use it?

Comment: In your sort function, first round for `i==0`, you compare `element[j]` and `element[j+1]` having `j==numitems-1` (so `j==4`). `element[4+1]` is outside your list of 5 numbers

Comment: the unsorted array was just extra from a previous version, didn't realize I still had it in the header there. Thank you for that @PaulMcKenzie....edc65, shouldn't the `for j < numItems - i` keep me from out of bounds though? I could just have traced it out wrong. Also why would that not cause consistent garbage output as apposed to now where sometimes it's right and other times it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sort function, change 
`for (int j = 0; j < numItems - i; j++)` to 
`for (int j = 0; j < numItems - i - 1; j++)`

Because if `i` is 0, there will be `j < numItems`, and `sorted[j] = sorted[j+1]` will be out of range.

Comment: ahhhhhh okay I see. didn't realize I was being caught by an off by 1 bug because I had that `-i` in there and it couldn't be anything else! However, one thing I am still curious about is why I wasn't consistently getting garbage output with the same input

Comment: Since you're going out of bounds, you are throwing into the mix random numbers into the sort.  You don't know what value you're picking up at those out-of-bounds positions, so maybe some may not affect your final output, and some will.